# How can I squash commits on the current Git branch using the fewest steps?

Tags: git, workflow

When I'm working in a branch for a new feature, I find myself frequently in the situation where I want to rebase my branch off of `master`, and squash all my commits to a single commit. I haven't really found a smooth way to do it. Usually it involves some combination of:

```bash
# checkout master
git checkout master
git pull

# merge-squash my changes onto that
git merge --squash my-feature-branch

# force my branch to the squashed commit
git checkout my-feature-branch
git reset --hard master

# put master back to the way it was
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

I'd like something that runs a bit smoother than this, especially without the extra checkouts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to simply use a soft reset. The advantage of this over an interactive rebase is that it will work efficiently for an arbitrary number of commits to squash (even hundreds or thousands):

```bash
git checkout feature
git reset --soft <commit-where-you-branched-off-master>
git commit -m "Your message here"
git rebase master
```

Comment: is there any automatic way to discover `<commit-where-you-branched-off-master>` (i.e., the least common ancestor of two branches)?

Comment: @pqnet you could probably do it with some form of [`git merge-base`](http://jk.gs/git-merge-base.html), though I don't know off the top of my head what you would need to pass in specifically to get the right ancestor.

Comment: given what I can read from the man page, it is just `git merge-base HEAD master`, or `git merge-base --fork-point my-feature-branch master`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
git rebase -i remote/master
```

then replace all `pick` with `squash` (or just `s`) except for  the first one. Save and exit. Commits will be squashed, the editor will be shown again to edit the commit message.
Push on master.

Comment: It would be even shorter to replace `pick` with `fixup` if the only the first commit's message is sufficient.

Comment: @donatello yes, but it is unlikely that the first commit has the right message anyway. Moreover, all possible variants are documented correctly as a comment on the same editor window that opens when you do `rebase -i` so he can choose and change accordingly